# Response.AddHeader("Location", "www.xyz.com") is prepending the existing domain to the redirected url like currentdomain/www.xyz.com

Tags: asp.net, redirect, header, request, location

**Current url** : www.abc.com

Response.AddHeader("Location", "www.xyz.com")

***after reidrection***

**url in browsers window** : www.abc.com/www.xyz.com

How to redirect directly to www.xyz.com without prepending the existing domain in url

Comment: Have you tried `http(s)://www.xyz.com`?